# Adjusting dessert recipes to accomodate a larger slow cooker

Tags: dessert

I have a recipe for Mississippi Mud cake that calls for a 3.5 qt slow cooker. I own a 6 qt. Do I need to double the recipe?

Comment: This is a fairly unusual application; you might want to provide the recipe.

Comment: It's possible that you'd scale by something less than double.  I'd assume you'd want to scale it based on the difference in the bottom surface of the cooker, so the thickness of the cake would remain constant.

Answer (score 2):

If your cake batter is to be poured into the slow cooker without the addition of a pan, yes, I would double the recipe to fit your larger vessel.